# Does Google allow placing adunits of other authors in one website?

Tags: google-adsense, google-adsense-policies

Am developing a code tutorial site and planning to use a model where the authors are given two Google Adsense Slots in their post/article pages.
One Square Ad Slot (200x200) in the middle of his post like after 4 paragraphs and one Rectangular Ad Slot (300 x250) at the right sidebar.

The website will take the Leader Board 728 x90 below the Top Navigation in the authors post/articles pages and also the home page and category pages.

I want to know if this is a good idea and Google allows it.

Answer (score 1):

That approach could be against Adsense policies because as it seems you won't control what each author publishes. If the content they publish doesn't complies [Adsense policy](https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/1112983?hl=en) then **your Adsense account** can be blocked.

> As you may know, AdSense publishers are ultimately responsible for the
>   traffic on their ads. For this reason, it’s critical that you
>   diligently monitor your ad traffic to ensure that your account is
>   compliant with our policies and not accruing invalid activity.

You should review each author content before putting ads on their articles.

Comment: how about i review the authors content before its published to the readers?

Comment: Yes, that is the suggested method when you have a platform with  contributed content.

Comment: Thx alot for the advice